# Load list of items in objectify

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, objectify

I have Question, Like and Hashtag entities. Also there is one to many relationship between Like and Question entities. I am using google cloud endpoints and my problem begins here. In my list method, I return 20 question as json. But for each question object in query I have to check if user is already liked the question and also fetch related hashtags that belongs to the question. How can I do the same operation by key only batch query. Otherwise, I do

```
ofy().load().type(Like.class)
                .filter("questionRef =", questionKey)
                .filter("accountRef =", accountKey).first().now();
```

for each object.

Like entity

```
@Entity
@Cache
public class Like {

  @Id
  @Getter
  protected Long id;

  @Index
  @Load
  @ApiResourceProperty(ignored = AnnotationBoolean.TRUE)
  private Ref<Account> accountRef;

  @Index
  @Load
  @ApiResourceProperty(ignored = AnnotationBoolean.TRUE)
  private Ref<Question> questionRef;

  @Index
  @Getter
  protected Date createdAt;

  Like() {
  }

  Like(Key<Account> accountKey) {
    this.accountRef = Ref.create(accountKey);
    this.createdAt = new Date();
  }
}
```

Hashtag entity

```
@Entity
@Cache
public class Hashtag implements Model<Hashtag> {

  @Id
  @Getter
  @ApiResourceProperty(ignored = AnnotationBoolean.TRUE)
  private Long id;

  @Index
  @Load
  @ApiResourceProperty(ignored = AnnotationBoolean.TRUE)
  private Ref<Question> questionRef;

  @Index
  @Getter
  @Setter
  private String text;

  private Hashtag() {
  }

  private Hashtag(Builder builder) {
    this.questionRef = builder.questionRef;
    this.text = builder.text;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several parts to this question.

First, hashtags: Just store hashtags in the Question as an indexed list property. Easy.

Second, likes: There are a couple ways to do this efficiently.

One is to create a Like entity with a natural key of "account:question" (use the stringified websafe key). This way you can do a batch get by key for all the {user,question} tuples. Some will be absent, some will be present. Reasonably efficient if you're only concerned about 20 questions, especially if you `@Cache` the Like.

Another is to create a separate Relation Index Entity that tracks all the likes of a user and just load those up each time. You can put 5k items in any list property, which means you'll need to juggle multiple entities when a user likes more than 5k things. But it's easy to load them all up with a single ancestor query. The RIE will need to be `@Parent`ed by the User.

On a separate note - don't call fields `thingRef`. It's just a `thing`. The data in the database is just a key. You can interchange `Ref<?>`, `Key<?>`, and the native low-level `Key`. Type information doesn't belong in database names.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. I will go my way with RIE. Shoud I use @Index for list property? And it will probably exceed 5k limit, so I think I must add new entities with task queue.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you can change the structure of your entities. If the answer is no, then there is no option other than the approach you have taken.

If yes, I would suggest structuring your `Question` to include the `Like` and `Hashtag` information as well.

```
@Entity
public class Question {
    @Id
    private long id;
    private Set<Key<Account>> likedBy;
    private List<String> hashtags;
}
```

For a question, you can retrieve all the information in one single query. Then collect all the `Account` keys and make another datastore query to retrieve all the people who have liked the question using keys as below:

```
Map<Key<Account>, Account> likedByAccounts = ofy().load().keys(accountKeys);
```

Comment: This is almost certainly a bad idea because the number of users that can like any particular question is unbounded.